# how does iteration work in ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, iterator, yield

I'm trying to understand how this iterator works:

```
def two_times          
    yield
    yield
end

two_times {puts "Hello"}
```

Does the second part call the method and then `yield` calls `{puts "Hello"}`?

Comment: I was wondering if the block code {puts "Hello"} was removed. Would it still work. And I just tried it without and I get an error --> no block given (yield). So, if using yield it needs that block code.

Comment: Try this: `yield unless block_given?`. It won't `yield` block if block is not given.

Comment: i did try it, but changed it to 'yield if block_given?', still got error with 'unless'

Comment: My bad. It should be `if` ( `yield if block_given?` ), as you said. Unless = if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, yes. The last line invokes the method `two_times` and passes in a block whose code prints out `Hello`. Each time the method executes `yield`, the block is executed.

Comment: In the code, could I also use do and end, which is same, except the precedence is higher with {}.

Comment: @user3155181 Did you try it?